# Simulating a controlled rectifier with CMOS , using Isis Proteus

Tags: simulation, cmos, rectifier, proteus, configuration

I am currently in the simulation phase of a controlled rectifier, and I must  use CMOS technology. However, I am a novice in this field and would appreciate detailed advice to help me get started. Here are some additional details:

1. Simulation Software: I am using Isis Proteus for my simulation.
2. Rectifier Configuration: My controlled rectifier needs to be implemented using CMOS components, but I am unsure of the best way to model them in the software.
3. Specific Parameters: I am not sure which CMOS parameters are crucial for achieving accurate simulation results. Guidance on configuring transistors, diodes, and other components would be greatly appreciated.
4. Input Source:For the simulation, I am using a sinusoidal alternative input source. Any advice on the best way to set up this source would be helpful.
5. Key Steps: If you could provide me with a concrete example with key steps for simulating a controlled rectifier with CMOS, it would be extremely beneficial.

Comment: I've never seen a CMOS "controlled rectifier". What is it? What does it do?

Comment: Simulating a controlled rectifier using CMOS

Comment: What problem is this intended to solve?

Comment: I don't know how to simulate this controlled rectifier , I want someone who Can help me and give me steps or ideas

Comment: What does "this" mean in the above sentence? What engineering purpose will be served by your "simulation"?